# Android incoming call when someone else is on call

Tags: android, call

How to know incoming call when someone else is on call in android. how to check that my call is waiting as someone else is on call.

Comment: your answer is here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/4834919/3092829

Comment: @Rashmi thanks for providing answer will check it

Comment: no problem.hope it helps

Comment: @Rashmi it helps me, this is what am looking for.

Comment: glad it did.Please mark the answer as accepted if the solution works for you so that it may help someone else with similar issues.