# How to detect if the call is answered

Tags: android

I need  to check if my outgoing call is answered or it is still ringing while calling someone.
is this possible?
It doesn't matter if the phone needs a root access.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect when phone is answered or rejected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684866/how-to-detect-when-phone-is-answered-or-rejected)

Comment: nope it's not , i don't need to check my phone if it's ringing ,i need to check if who i called answered my call

Comment: Have you checked this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424050/how-can-i-determine-if-there-is-a-call-ringing-on-line-2-e-g-call-waiting or maybe this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250455/detect-if-an-outgoing-call-has-been-answered

Comment: Yup , nothing useful

Comment: The first answer in that question explains how to check if the state has changed *ie if the phone was answered*. There's quite a few answers out there and in @QuintinBalsdons suggestions that should work.

Comment: it seems there are 3 states of phone states , nothing is useful for me, that's why i said  it doesn't matter if it needs a root access to change something

Comment: do we have a solution for this ? off hook is getting called even if the call is not answered.